# updating graph on each iteration of a loop

Tags: java, multithreading, graph

I have a bubble graph that I need to update the radius of each bubble on every iteration of a loop. Each iteration the loop analyses a tweet and updates the topic count and then each bubble is updated with this information.

The problem I'm having is that the bubbles just grow once all the tweets have been analysed and not after each one.

I need the graph to update after each iteration of the loop so you can see the analysis taking place.

Here's the code I use to try and do this currently.

```
 private void onLiveDemoButtonClicked(ActionEvent event) throws IOException, JWNLException {
    fFilePath = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\Lynsey\\Documents\\FinalYearProject\\words\\test.txt");
    Scanner scanner =  new Scanner(fFilePath, ENCODING.name());

    int tweetCount = 0;
    Tweets tweetDemo = new Tweets();
    while(scanner.hasNextLine()) {
   // if(tweetCount <= 100) {
      tweetCount++;
     // System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());
      String currentTweet = scanner.nextLine();
      tweetDemo.processLineByLine(currentTweet);

      XYChart.Series<Number, Number> s = liveDemoBubbleChart.getData().get(0);
      s.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(5, 5, ProjectProperties.getInstance().getSportsTweetsCount()));
      XYChart.Series<Number, Number> p = liveDemoBubbleChart.getData().get(1);
      p.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(25, 25, ProjectProperties.getInstance().getPoliticsTweetsCount()));
      XYChart.Series<Number, Number> d = liveDemoBubbleChart.getData().get(2);
      d.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(55, 55, ProjectProperties.getInstance().getIllnessTweetsCount()));
      XYChart.Series<Number, Number> w = liveDemoBubbleChart.getData().get(3);
      w.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(75, 75, ProjectProperties.getInstance().getWarTweetsCount()));
      XYChart.Series<Number, Number> m = liveDemoBubbleChart.getData().get(4);
      m.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(95, 95, ProjectProperties.getInstance().getMoneyTweetsCount()));
      XYChart.Series<Number, Number> u = liveDemoBubbleChart.getData().get(5);
      u.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(115, 115, ProjectProperties.getInstance().getUndefinedTweetsCount()));




    }
```

Comment: We can't really tell what is going on without knowing more details: where do you update the radius? What does XYChart do? Etc.

Comment: @GiovanniBotta The radius is updated in this while loop. The XYChart displays bubbles where the size of the bubble represents the number of tweets for that topic

Answer (score 0):

For a quick dirty fix try adding the following to the end of your current code...

`try{Thread.sleep(1000);}catch(InterruptedException e){}`

This causes the current thread to sleep for 1000 milliseconds, this will yields processor time to other threads such as the rendering thread, giving it a chance to update the graph. If this does not make it begin animating then its probably not a threading issue and is more likely a issue with the graph rendering code not getting called until the very end in your code for some reason.

Then adjust the 1000 milliseconds as necessary to get reasonably good animation.